# How to structure firebase rules with friend requests?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firebase Cloud Firestore app with a collection of `friendships` and a collection of `friendship-requests`. Each document in these collections has the `uid` of the two friends (for `friendships`) or potential friends (for `friendship-requests`). Once the second friend accepts the request, the document is moved from the `friendship-requests` collection to the `friendships` collection.

When the app loads, the current user queries the `friendships` collection for documents that contain their `uid`, makes a list of the other `uid`'s in those documents (these are the `uid`'s of their friends), then queries the `users` collection using this list to retrieve data about their friends.

What is a good strategy for how I could write firebase rules to stop people from accessing the data of users that haven't accepted their friend request?

Comment: When you say "general strategy", what are you looking for?  The general strategy for *all* security rules is to allow only the access to each user that they should have to specific data.  Anything after that is a matter of actually writing the rules that meet those requirements.  The documentation is full of information about how rules work.  Do you have a specific problem about writing rules that you're trying to address, based on what you know from the docs?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: @DougStevenson By general strategy, I mean that I'm a bit lost as to where I should start for how to check inside documents of the friendships collection for the right uid's and stop people from forging friendships documents. Is there a way to query collections within the firebase rules, like a more powerful version of the get() function?

Comment: No, security rules do not have querying capability.  That would not scale at all for large collections.  You will need to structure your data in such a way that works with the capabilities of security rules.

Comment: @DougStevenson can you please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Security rules do not have querying capability. That would not scale at all for large collections. You will need to structure your data in such a way that works with the capabilities of security rules.

Comment: Is it still true? Can we use query in realtime DB rules now as of today?

Comment: @JaydipKalkani I am certain you will never be able to use rules like this, for the same reason I mentioned in the answer.  That will never change.